# Robot Framework: Is there a way to set a secure test variable?

Tags: security, logging, robotframework

I am using Robot Framework, and was setting up a function that uses the Built In Libraries "Set Test Variable" command to reset a password variable, however it is storing the new variable name in the Robot Framework Log.

Is there any existing keyword to securely set a variable during the test so the actual variable change is not displayed in the Robot Framework log? Some secure keyword that may do this, similar to SeleniumLibrary's Input Password for typing passwords into fields, but doesn't store the password in the log?

This is how I currently have it, but the new variable is displayed in the log output:

```
*** Keywords ***
Set Password Variable keyword
    Set Test Variable    ${current_pw}    ${new_pw}
```

Answer (score 3):

Given that logging is central to test execution, have a secure test step is something that in my view somewhat conflicting. The best approach is that the system-under-test does not contain any interesting information and the used accounts do not provide access to any other system.

In addition using temporary accounts, only active for the duration of the (short) test cycle, also helps in securing an environment where the information is of value. However, as faulty software may trigger screenshots or log information otherwise not logged, the log files generated in of these types of t tests should only be accessible to those employees who have access to the original data.

With all of this said, there are a few things you can do to help your cause in Robot Script.

First one is to create all the required variables from the command line or using variable files. As they are created before logging is started there not logged.

Second one is to create a custom python keyword that fetches and uses the secure value. This prevents any logging and most likely and leaking of values.

Last one is to utilize the `Set Log Level` keyword. However, this approach has a down side that you need to assume that the in-between steps can inadvertently increase or decrease the log level permanently in case of a failure. This is why I added the `[Teardown]` example to handle such cases.

```
*** Variables ***
${pwd}    Default Pass
${new_pwd}    Secure Password Value

*** Test Cases ***
TC
    ${pwd}        Set Variable     Logged Password Value

    ${prev_lvl}   Set Log Level    NONE
    ${pwd}        Set Variable     
    ${prev_lvl}   Set Log Level    ${prev_lvl}

    [Teardown]    Run Keyword If    "${prev_lvl}"<>"NONE"    Set Log Level    ${prev_lvl}
```